# List all combinations of $10$ numbers chosen from $1$ to $40$

Tags: combinatorics

Can you provide all possible combination of numbers $1$ to $40$ by $10$?
This will be the same for question like All Possible $6/45$ Lottery Number Combinations. It just that what I need is $10/40$, and yes I need all the number list.
I know that this is to much but, if it just possible. Can you make the list?
Please please please I need this thanks in advance!!!
The problem is that I cannot run or make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All possible combinations of 10 numbers in the range of 1 to 40 is a list with $\begin{pmatrix}40 \\ 10\end{pmatrix}=847,660,528$ entries. Generating this list is feasible for a computer but placing it as an answer would be longer then the site would permit.

Comment: There would be too many to write them in the margins as Fermat would have said.

Comment: are you able to email it to me?

Comment: No I am not. Even if I was it would be a considerable amount of effort.  For an impression of the scale of this number there are enough lines that I could give every person in the USA two of them and still have lines left over.

Comment: I understand. I appreciate it thanks a lot!